# Keep scale of element on zooming

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

The d3js library has a built-in behavior called `zoom`, which applies dragging and zooming in the selected element and its children. It is hard to keep the scale and good visualization when you have a great zoom scale, and text labels, for example, can become ilegible.

I'm trying to find a way to ignore a **specific** element when zooming the area, but I don't see a way to achieve that.

In this case, there is a `circle` and a `text` inside a `g`. When I zoom a simple pack layout, I have the following behavior, [with the following code](http://jsfiddle.net/haskellcamargo/0gmL3ovx/):

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .translate([0, 0])
  .scale(1.0)
  .scaleExtent([0.1, 3])
  .on("zoom", function() {
    child.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate +
    ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  });
```

[image]

I need to prevent `text` from being zoomed, staying static:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve that or it is neeed to rewrite the zoom behavior and reapply the scroll events also?

Comment: You can put the text in a different group element and use [semantic zooming](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957) to manage it's positioning

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, this was the basis I used to construct the text label, but I'm looking for event application with the common `zoom` behavior, with dragging and scroll managed by `d3.behavior.zoom()`, unless no other alternatives be found, something more generic.

Comment: @CoolBlue, semantic zooming is pretty good for this task!

Comment: Yes, it's probably the simplest way. If you had enough headache pills (or if your Jason Davies) you could use something like `trans = child.node().transformToElement(myTextNode)` and then use the [SVGMatrix interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InterfaceSVGMatrix) to make and apply a new transform that delivers the semantic zoom effect.